# Is there a word which means “something that masquerades as truth but isn’t it”

Tags: word-usage

Would it be a hunch or a notion. Maybe a belief? It’s misconstured as proof but isn’t because it doesn’t possess the requirements to be proof

Comment: Is there such a word in your native language. Can you give an example of how you would use this word?

Comment: What do you think are requirements for proof of something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "fallacy" is argument that might appear true, but is an error in reasoning, and will invalidate the argument. For example:

> If you argue
>
> > Since the students have no questions concerning the topics discussed in class, the students are ready for a test.
>
> You are making an error. This is the "Fallacy of Appeal to Ignorance" as the lack of evidence that the students are ignorant does not prove that they are not ignorant.  An absence of evidence is not evidence of absence.

Answer (score 0):

In contemporary usage, the word **myth** can mean "something which people accept and perpetuate as fact but which is not based on fact". The phrase **urban legend** has much the same meaning.

> That the Inuit have more than [50 words for snow](https://www.washingtonpost.com/national/health-science/there-really-are-50-eskimo-words-for-snow/2013/01/14/e0e3f4e0-59a0-11e2-beee-6e38f5215402_story.html?noredirect=on&utm_term=.a52792346727) was thought to be a myth.